# Weird behaviour of NOT

Tags: vba, winapi, boolean

I'm experiencing some weird behaviour of boolean variables; the following code prints both "Hello" and "There", meaning `result` & `NOT result` both evaluate to True

```
Dim result As Boolean
result = PostMessage(Application.hWnd, 275, 0, 0)
Debug.Print "Post message: "; result
If result Then Debug.Print "Hello"
If Not result Then Debug.Print "There"
```

Outputs

```
Post message: True
Hello
There
```

---

According to the docs, [PostMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagea) is declared like this:

```cpp
BOOL PostMessageA(
  HWND   hWnd,
  UINT   Msg,
  WPARAM wParam,
  LPARAM lParam
);
```

With the comment:

> If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.

Here's how I have it in VBA:

```
Public Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" ( _
                        ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, _
                        ByVal msg As Long, _
                        ByVal wParam As LongPtr, _
                        ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As Boolean
```

So what's causing the weird behaviour? How do I get around it?

Comment: `PostMessage` doesn't return a VBA `Boolean`. It returns a 32 bit integer. 0 means the function succeeded, non zero means that it failed. Change your `Declare` to correct this mistake. Refer to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagea

Comment: The documentation states "If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero." which is equivalent to `True` in VBA, though. What is the value of result if you step through the code?

Comment: ^^Agree with David that the return value is non-Boolean (although I think the interpretation is reversed). I tested with the correction and it worked for me. (BTW it would help a lot with these kinds of things if you'd include a [mcve] in the question. `Handle` and `WM_Timer` are missing...)

Comment: @CindyMeister Generating a safe handle to use is kind of long and irrelevant; I assume sending a random timer message to the Application's message queue shouldn't have too many unforeseen consequences so I've updated the example:)

Comment: @Nacorid That's what I thought. The function actually return 1 for success, 0 for fail. I thought VBA's default conversion would put 0 = False, <>0  = True, as is indeed the case when you print. But I believe the problem lies in the fact that VBA represents True as -1

Comment: No. It returns non zero for success, not guaranteed to be 1. And yes, I got the logic reversed in my first comment, sorry.

Comment: Here is more context - "logical" operators in VBA work as *bitwise* operators when applied to numbers. The linked answer talks about `And` and `Or`, but it applies to `Not` as well...https://stackoverflow.com/a/8047021/58845

Answer (score 1):

Although *normally* a VBA `Boolean` holds either `True` (`-1`) or `False` (`0`), it is possible to insert another value into this type with some trickery.

This is what is happening here: your mis-specified API call is returning an integral type with a value that's neither `-1` nor `0`.

Since `NOT(a)` is `0` if and only if `a` is `-1`, both `Hello` and `There` will be printed if the payload in the `Boolean` is anything other than `-1` or `0`.

Comment: What's wrong with this answer? Is the reason it gives not an accurate explanation for the observed behaviour?

Comment: @Greedo This answer is correct. That is exactly what happens in VBA when you put something like `1` into a `Boolean` with something like `CopyMemory` or an API call. I cannot find my own answer about it.

Answer (score 0):

## Malformed Bools

After a bit of poking and prodding around, I've been able to produce a minimal working example of this issue without the use of any API functions

```
Private Sub stuff(ByRef into, ByVal val)
    Let into = val
End Sub

Public Sub QuantumBoolTest()

    Dim Schrodinger As Boolean
    Call stuff(Schrodinger, &HFFFE)

    Debug.Print "Schrodinger    :=", Schrodinger & vbCrLf & _
                "NOT Schrodinger:=", (Not Schrodinger)

End Sub
```

which outputs

```
Schrodinger    :=           True
NOT Schrodinger:=           True
```

when executed. As such, it can has been shown that the behaviour you are seeing may be reproduced by stuffing a sixteen bit (in this case signed) integer into the memory address of the bool.

So, in short. your hypothesis is approximately correct.

---

Interestingly, it seems that the variable now behaves as if it was a signed 16 bit int. This can be seen in a couple of ways, namely, in how it reacts differently to the `Sgn` function

```
?sgn(Schrodinger)
-1 

?sgn(Not Schrodinger)
 1 

?sgn(True)
-1 

?sgn(False)
 0
```

and how it responds to the `AND` and `IMP` functions,

```
?Schrodinger AND NOT Schrodinger
False

?Schrodinger IMP NOT Schrodinger 
True
```

under which it behaves as if the variable was a signed int,

```
?&HFFFE AND NOT &HFFFE
0

?&HFFFE IMP NOT &HFFFE
1
```

and not as if it was a boolean variable.

```
?TRUE AND NOT TRUE
False

?TRUE IMP FALSE
False
```

Comment: Just a quick note - the functions shown above are immediate window functions, and are all observed by using a breakpoint after the `Call stuff(Schrodinger, &HFFFE)` call.

Comment: There wasn't really a need for much guesswork. It is documented that `Boolean` is 16 bits, that `False` is `0` (all bits cleared) and that `True` is the bitwise negation of `0` which is `&hFFFF`, or `-1` (all bits set). The `Not` operator expects `True` to be `-1`.

Comment: @GSerg would you mind sharing that documentation where you got that from (specifically the bit about it being 16 bits)? I had never seen anything that indicated that behavior and would be excited to see any further information on it

Comment: Um... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/boolean-data-type?

Answer (score -1):

I guess what's happening is that under the hood, Booleans are saved in VBA as 16-bit integers

```
False = 0 = &H0000 = 0000 0000 0000 0000

True = -1 = &HFFFF = 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

And `NOT` does a bitwise NOT to turn all those 1s into 0s

My function however returns 32-bit 1 which is implicitly cast to 16-bit 1 to store in the `Boolean` return variable

```
Result = 1 = &H0001 = 0000 0000 0000 0001
```

As the value is not 0, it is interpreted by VBA as True (or perhaps more accurately as *isn't `False`* since it is not the same value as a normal True)

But bitwise `NOT Result` gives

```
NOT Result = -2 = &HFFFE = 1111 1111 1111 1110
```

Which is also non-zero so is also interpreted as True, giving the behaviour observed.

---

So to remedy this; either explicitly check the return value by storing it as its native type:

```
Declare PostMessage(...)  As Long

'...

Dim result as Boolean
result = PostMessage(...) <> 0
```

Or refrain from using NOT and instead check for False*:

```
Declare PostMessage(...)  As Boolean

'...

Dim result as Boolean
result = PostMessage(...)

If result = False Then
    '... do blah
```

**I wouldn't necessarily advise doing this because it makes the code unreadable - I only considered it as an option because it allows you to use intellisense on the return value. But I think it works*

Comment: Have to downvote for the content starting "or refrain".

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Why? Sure it's not especially readable and I would personally choose the first option, but it works doesn't it? Or have I made a mistake?

Comment: `PostMessage` returns a 32 bit integer. Compare that against `0`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes I agree that the return type is not a VBA native Boolean. However I think (with care) it can be treated as one. I may be missing something, but I don't think I've written anything *incorrect*, just *inadvisable* - added a note to that effect. I was worried about downcasting errors, but [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions) imply Boolean conversion won't be affected by that. So is there something fundamentally incorrect about this answer (and indeed the other one)?

Comment: I told you what it would take for me to retract my vote.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Oh no, don't worry I'm not too concerned about the votes if they are for stylistic concerns, because that's not what the original question actually asks. I just want to know whether the logic I've detailed here is wrong, the downvotes on the other answer with similar logic would suggest it is?

Comment: I find it hard to be motivated to reverse engineer such implementation details. As a general principle with interop it is best to map at binary level as literally as possible, and then wrap for convenience in the target language.

Comment: Greedo the only difference that I am observing is that while indicating `NOT Result = 65534 = &HFFFE` makes quite a bit of sense, in the context of this question, it would make more sense to treat result as a signed 16 bit integer and read the value as equaling `-2`, as the result of `CLng(NOT Result)` is `-2`. I observe the same values out of `CDbl` and `CInt`