# How to change my code to get the values into arrays

Tags: vba, excel

I followed some array tutorials, but my code in VBA is too difficult for me to change it into arrays for my basic knowledge.

Can anyone help?

This is my code:

```
Sub InternExtern()

Dim source, addrescell, destination As Range
Dim Sourcevalue As String


For Each source In Range("E6", Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
 If source.Value <> "" Then
    For Each addrescell In Range("address_table_names").Rows
             If addrescell.Cells(1).Value <> "" And InStr(source.Offset(0, 23).Value, "Extern") = 0 Then
               SourceName = addrescell.Cells(1).Value
               Sourcevalue = addrescell.Cells(1, 4).Value
                    If InStr(UCase(source), UCase(SourceName)) <> 0 Then
                      If InStr(Sourcevalue, "10.") <> 0 Or InStr(Sourcevalue, "192.168.") <> 0 Or IsInternal(addrescell.Offset(0, 3).Value) Then
                       source.Offset(0, 23) = "Intern"
                       Else: source.Offset(0, 23) = "Extern"
                      End If
                    End If
                      If InStr(source, "-ext-") <> 0 Or InStr(source, "any") <> 0 Or InStr(source, "-EXT-") <> 0 Then
                      source.Offset(0, 23) = "Extern"
                      End If
                      If InStr(source, "any") <> 0 And InStr(source.Offset(0, -1).Value, "FW-Peering") = 0 Then
                      source.Offset(0, 23) = "Intern"
                      End If

            End If
            Next addrescell
End If
Next source
```

My goal of adding the column values into arrays is to make it faster.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To make _what_ faster, anyways?

Comment: You did not properly declare all your Range variables. `source` and `addrescell` are Variant based on the way you dimensioned them.

Comment: Your [previous question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/23923/2726) got migrated to CR, and was well answered by [Dick Kusleika](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/23956/2726).  Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite see how putting something in an array would be helpful. You'd have to take it out again sometime.

You might try disabling `Application.ScreenUpdating` and `Application.Calculation` while your loop runs and turning it back on at the end.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
' your loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

If you could explain what the code is doing or what you want to do we might be able to help more. Using a worksheet function like @sehe suggested might be a much better solution.

**Update**

Just looked at your link to codereview and one of the answers show that its fairly simple and quick to create an array copy of your worksheet and to re-apply the modified array to the worksheet. Not seen that before, pretty cool stuff.

<strike>While Arrays might be quicker, I think in your case they would just add a lot of extra complexity as you use methods of the objects that wont be there when you convert it to an array.</strike>

Assuming you add the cell Address to the array (otherwise you have no context to the sheet)

`Array(1).Offset(0,1) = <not going to happen>`

`Range(Array(1)).Offset(0,1) = <going to work>`

So you'd be going back to objects to do your stuff, unless you have lots of arrays, that may or may be redundant.

Since I'm not 100% sure what the goal of your function is this might not help at all!
I think you might have some extra (unneeded) iterations of your internal for loop. If at the sections marked `'HERE` basically mean that you've completed that iteration you can exit the loop and goto the next parent loop.

```
For Each source In Range("E6", Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    If source.Value <> "" Then
        For Each addrescell In Range("address_table_names").Rows
            If addrescell.Cells(1).Value <> "" Then ' vba doesn't shortcircuit
                If InStr(source.Offset(0, 23).Value, "Extern") = 0 Then
                    SourceName = addrescell.Cells(1).Value
                    Sourcevalue = addrescell.Cells(1, 4).Value
                    If InStr(UCase(source), UCase(SourceName)) <> 0 Then
                        If InStr(Sourcevalue, "10.") <> 0 Or InStr(Sourcevalue, "192.168.") <> 0 Or IsInternal(addrescell.Offset(0, 3).Value) Then
                            source.Offset(0, 23) = "Intern"
                            ' HERE
                            Exit For
                        Else
                            source.Offset(0, 23) = "Extern"
                            ' HERE
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                    If InStr(source, "-ext-") <> 0 Or InStr(source, "any") <> 0 Or InStr(source, "-EXT-") <> 0 Then
                        source.Offset(0, 23) = "Extern"
                        ' HERE
                        Exit For
                    End If
                    If InStr(source, "any") <> 0 Then ' again, no shortcircuit
                        If InStr(source.Offset(0, -1).Value, "FW-Peering") = 0 Then
                            source.Offset(0, 23) = "Intern"
                            ' HERE
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next addrescell
    End If
Next source
```

[Information about `shortcircuit-ing`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015471/does-the-vba-and-operator-evaluate-the-second-argument-when-the-first-is-false), Having a nested if is faster than using `and`, not lightspeed, but saves you one comparison. If you're doing lots of iteration it can add up (a little anyway)

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer but on my previous question, they told me to make arrays. What u just said, thats what i already did. here is my previous question: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/23923/improve-vba-code-excel

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend making a worksheet function out of it:

- A somewhat useful example is http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/braindump/building-complex-user-defined-functions-with-visual-basic-applications-in-excel/
- (sadly better docs are hard to find, will try to find more)

That way, you can just type a formula in the calculated columns

```
 =InternExtern(E6)
```

And the cell will only be recalculated if you do a full recalc, you recompile the VBA project or the source value changes!