# How does VBA treat 'or' statements

Tags: excel, vba

I've got the following code

```
Dim qt As QueryTable
For Each qt In ActiveSheet.QueryTables
    If qt.Sql = SQLSTRING Then Exit For
Next qt
If qt Is Nothing Or qt.Sql <> SQLSTRING Then 
     DoStuff 
End If
```

I have a question because I can see that 'qt is nothing' is evaluating to true, but on the same line, I get a '91: Object variable or With block variable not set' error.  It's not an issue as I can easily catch the error, but tbh I was surprised, as I thought if the first clause of an 'or' evaluates to true, it shouldn't even try to evaluate the second clause...is this not something I can rely on in vba?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7015575/2258  Answer: VBA does not short circuit.

Comment: Heh, our comments are less than a second apart :)

Comment: Fair enough to mark as duplicate :) hope you can understand why it didn't come up in my searches though!

Answer (score 0):

**VBA** is not so clever, use:

```
If qt Is Nothing Then
    DoStuff
Else
    If qt.Sql <> SQLSTRING Then
        DoStuff
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Instead of saying "VBA is not so clever", which really doesn't explain anything, state that VBA doesn't do short-circuiting.  Which is coincidentally explained by the links above.