# Advance to Next Item from Within a For-Next Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have a For-Next loop.  Within the loop I test several different criteria and if any test fails, then I am ready at that point to skip the remainder of the code in the loop and advance to the "next" item.  The way I currently handle this is with a GoTo statement that takes me to the line right before "Next".  I'd prefer not to use a GoTo statement, is there another way to advance to the "next" item from within a For-Next loop?  TIA!

```
For x = 1 to 10
    Test 1
    If Test 1 fails then
        GoTo Line1
    End if

    Test 2
    If Test 2 fails then
        GoTo Line1
    End if
    .
    .
    .
    If all tests pass then
        add item to array
    End if
Line1:    
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a workaround for the lack of a `continue` keyword:

```
For x = 1 to 10
    Do
        Test 1
        If Test 1 fails then
            Exit Do
        End if

        Test 2
        If Test 2 fails then
            Exit Do
        End if
        .
        .
        .
        If all tests pass then
            add item to array
        End if
    Loop While False
Next
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who responded, there is a lot of useful information in all of the answers.  Given how my code is structured, this answer best fit the bill.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is no `continue`-like statement in a `for` loop in vba. (The related control structure `Exit For` does exist but that's of no help here).

And it's good that you have reservations on using a `GoTo`: they do make code hard to follow.

Your best bet is to put the code in the loop in a separate function and use `Exit Function` within that function at appropriate points. You can even then relay error codes back to the caller so helping the code to scale.

Answer (score 0):

You can use if else ladder :

```
For x = 1 to 10
if test 1 
else if test 2
else if test 3
. 
.
.
.
else
  add item to array
end if
Next
```

Besides GoTo there is not any direct way to jump in between your code,
Hope this might help.

Comment: That's fine if the tests are mutually exclusive.

Comment: In VBA you want to use `ElseIf` to construct logical ladders, as `Else If` would have a slightly different meaning

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have too many tests, you could you use the `Not` condition and build a nested `If` statement. This should have almost the same effect as what you're asking for, since any failed test would end that `If` statement and move the code to the next X in your loop without executing the following tests.

Here's an example of what I mean -- a two test loop that builds an array containing the numbers 5 through 10:

```
Sub TestConditionalPass()

    Dim intX As Integer
    Dim intArray() As Integer
        ReDim intArray(1)

    For intX = 1 To 10
        If Not intX -2 < 1 Then
            If Not intX * 2 < 10 Then
                ReDim Preserve intArray(UBound(intArray) + 1)
                    intArray(UBound(intArray)) = intX
            End If
        End If
    Next intX

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are preforming an action only if all tests succeed, then do the if-statement with ands.  [VBA doesn't short circuit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015471/does-the-vba-and-operator-evaluate-the-second-argument-when-the-first-is-false) the tests, (i.e. it will evaluate each test case, even if the first one returns false.)  I would suggest encapsulating each test in a function that returns a Boolean to keep your code tidy.

```
If Test1()  and _
   Test2()  and _
   testn()  THEN
    add item to array
End if
```

Another way is to make use of a Boolean variable in your code, like this

```
Dim Success as Boolean
Success=True
Test 1
If Test 1 fails then
    Success=false
End if

Test 2
If Test 2 fails then
    Success=false
End if
.
.
.
If Success then
    add item to array
End if
```

If the tests are expensive, you can add an inner if statement checking to see if we need to evaluate the next test like this

```
 If Success Then
    If Test n fails then
       Success=false
    End If
End if
```