# 'And' condition evaluated even if previous condition is false in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

For example:

```
Dim name As String: name = "NaN"

' Doesn't generate an error:
If IsNumeric(name) Then
    Dim iv As Integer: iv = CInt(name)
    If iv > 0 Then
        ' Do something
    End If
End If

' Does generate error 13 on 'CInt(name)': Types don't match
If IsNumeric(name) And CInt(name) > 0 Then
    ' Do something
End If
```

Why is the second condition `CInt(name) > 0` even evaluated with the single if statement? Or is this just what VBA does? I'm used to write C# code which doesn't have this kind of behavior.

Comment: see [vba short circuit logic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015471/does-the-vba-and-operator-evaluate-the-second-argument-when-the-first-is-false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or is this just what VBA does?

Yes.

Use this instead:

```
If IsNumeric(name) Then 
    If CInt(name) > 0 Then
        ' Do something
    End If
End If
```

or any other method from the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015471/does-the-vba-and-operator-evaluate-the-second-argument-when-the-first-is-false) linked by amdixon.

Comment: I see. Too bad that you can't use C# in Excel to write macros :(