# What is the meaning of "Not Rng Is Nothing" (within the if) in the code below

Tags: excel, vba

What is the meaning of `Not Rng Is Nothing` (within the `If`) in the code below?

> Suppose you have a list of produce (column `A`) with totals next to
> them. If you want to find any total (column `B`) equal to zero and
> place `LOW` in the cell next to it (column `C`), do this:
>
> ```vb
> Set Rng = Range("B1:B16").Find(What:="0", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
> Rng.Offset(, 1).Value = "LOW"
> ```
>
> ```vb
> Sub MyOffset()
>     With Range("B1:B16")
>         Set Rng = .Find(What:="0", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
>         If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
>             firstAddress = Rng.Address
>             Do
>                 Rng.Offset(, 1).Value = "LOW"
>                 Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
>             Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> firstAddress
>         End If
>     End With
> End Sub
> ```

Answer (score 1):

[Find()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) method looks for a cell in range it's being called upon matching the criteria specified in its parameters ("What", "LookIn", "LookAt", ...) and returns either the found cell reference (a `Range` object) or the null reference object (referenced with the keyword `Nothing`) if no matches found

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I would think it's important to point out in the answer that this `Is Nothing` check is pointless because VBA [does not short circuit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7015471/11683), so on a Nothing `Rng` the `Rng.Address` will throw exception anyway.