# using AND condtion in vba

Tags: excel, vba

When I am using "AND" condition an error saying "run time error 1004, method range of object global failed" occurs. My code is working fine if I remove and condition may be there is wrong use of "and" Pls any help will be great support. Thanks

```
Private Sub okButton_Click()
Dim i As Double, dt1 As String, dtt1 As String
Dim dt2 As String, dtt2 As String
dt1 = ComboBox1.Value
dtt1 = CDate(dt1)
dt2 = ComboBox2.Value
dtt2 = CDate(dt2)
Debug.Print dtt2
For i = 2 To 6724
If Range("A" & i).Value >= dtt1 And Range("A", i).Value <= dtt2 Then
Rows(i).Select
With Selection.Interior
.ColorIndex = 36
.Pattern = xlSolid
End With
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using comma (,) in your if condition please replace ',' with '&' 
Have corrected the code please refer below code:

```
Dim i As Double, dt1 As String
Dim dtt1 As Date
Dim dt2 As String
Dim dtt2 As Date

dt1 = ComboBox1.Value
dtt1 = CDate(dt1)
dt2 = ComboBox2.Value
dtt2 = CDate(dt2)
Debug.Print dtt2

For i = 2 To 6724
    If Range("A" & i).Value >= dtt1 And Range("A" & i).Value <= dtt2 Then
        Rows(i).Select
        With Selection.Interior
        .ColorIndex = 36
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        End With
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Silly mistake, Thanks a lot, I have waste my lot of time for this.

Answer (score 2):

As VBA doesn't [short circuit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015471/does-the-vba-and-operator-evaluate-the-second-argument-when-the-first-is-false) you should break your `AND` into two `IF`s so you don't process the second test if the first isn't passed.

Code also removes `Select` and turns off `ScreenUpdating`, would be faster still if you used `AutoFilter` rather than a range loop.

```
Sub Recut()
Dim i As Double, dt1 As String
Dim dtt1 As Date
Dim dt2 As String
Dim dtt2 As Date

dt1 = ComboBox1.Value
dtt1 = CDate(dt1)
dt2 = ComboBox2.Value
dtt2 = CDate(dt2)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 2 To 6724
    If Range("A" & i).Value >= dtt1 Then
        If Range("A" & i).Value <= dtt2 Then
            With Rows(i).Interior
            .ColorIndex = 36
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            End With
         End If
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a minor typo in this line:

```
 If Range("A" & i).Value >= dtt1 And Range("A", i).Value <= dtt2 Then
```

The error is because`Range("A", i).Value` is not a valid range, because `"A"` is not a range or a cell.

Change to:

```
If Range("A" & i).Value >= dtt1 And Range("A" & i).Value <= dtt2 Then
```