# Replace text (Replace href by a hyperlink)

Tags: html, vba, excel, replace, href

There is a program that works fine . The result of her work is the output in Excel of the table of elements (href) (every element look like :  about:new_ftour.php?champ=2604&f_team=412&tour=110). I want to replace href by a hyperlink (replace the text  “about:” by  “http://allscores.ru/soccer/” ). After a line (oRange.Value=data)  I added a line (oRange.Replace What:="about:", Replacement:="http://allscores.ru/soccer/"). But for mysterious reasons the program gives an error (Run-time error ‘91’) . In the line (Loop While Not r Is Nothing And r.Address <> firstAddress And iLoop < 19).

```
    Sub Softгиперссылки()
      Application.DisplayAlerts = False


     Call mainмассивы

      Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End Sub


    Sub mainмассивы()
    Dim r As Range
     Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim iLoop As Long
    Dim book1 As Workbook
    Dim sheetNames(1 To 19) As String
    Dim Ssilka As String


    sheetNames(1) = "Лист1"
    sheetNames(2) = "Лист2"
    sheetNames(3) = "Лист3"
    sheetNames(4) = "Лист4"
    sheetNames(5) = "Лист5"
    sheetNames(6) = "Лист6"
    sheetNames(7) = "Лист7"
    sheetNames(8) = "Лист8"
    sheetNames(9) = "Лист9"
    sheetNames(10) = "Лист10"
    sheetNames(11) = "Лист11"
    sheetNames(12) = "Лист12"
    sheetNames(13) = "Лист13"
    sheetNames(14) = "Лист14"
    sheetNames(15) = "Лист15"
    sheetNames(16) = "Лист16"
    sheetNames(17) = "Лист17"
    sheetNames(18) = "Лист18"
    sheetNames(19) = "Лист19"

   'пропускаем ошибку

    Set book1 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Super M\Проект ставки\Поиск решения\Усов 7\Условия для андердогов\пробная.xlsm")


   iLoop = 0

   With book1.Worksheets("Лист1").Range("S34:S99") '<--| open wanted workbook and refer to cells "U33:U99" in its worksheet "7"

    Set r = .Find(What:="1", LookIn:=xlValues) '<--| the Find() method is called on the range referred to in the preceding With statement
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = r.Address
        Do
            iLoop = iLoop + 1
            Ssilka = r.Offset(, -14).Hyperlinks.Item(1).Address
            .Parent.Parent.Worksheets(sheetNames(1)).Activate
            .Parent.Parent.Save
            extractTable Ssilka, book1, iLoop

            Set r = .FindNext(r) '<--| the FindNext() method is still called on the same range as in the preceding  .Find() statement
        Loop While Not r Is Nothing And r.Address <> firstAddress And iLoop < 19 '<--| exit loop if either you hit the first link or completed three loops
    End If
    End With
    book1.Save
    book1.Close



    Exit Sub


    End Sub


    Function extractTable(Ssilka As String, book1 As Workbook, iLoop As Long)
    Dim oDom As Object, oTable As Object, oRow As Object
    Dim iRows As Integer, iCols As Integer
    Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
    Dim data()
    Dim oHttp As Object
    Dim oRegEx As Object
    Dim sResponse As String
    Dim oRange As Range



   ' get page
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
   oHttp.Open "GET", Ssilka, False
    oHttp.Send

   ' cleanup response
    sResponse = StrConv(oHttp.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    Set oHttp = Nothing

    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))

    Set oRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With oRegEx
    .MultiLine = True
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern = "<(script|SCRIPT)[\w\W]+?</\1>"
    sResponse = .Replace(sResponse, "")
    End With
     Set oRegEx = Nothing

    ' create Document from response
     Set oDom = CreateObject("htmlFile")
     oDom.Write sResponse
    DoEvents

    ' table with results, indexes starts with zero
   Set oTable = oDom.getelementsbytagname("table")(3)

   DoEvents

   iRows = oTable.Rows.Length
   iCols = oTable.Rows(1).Cells.Length

     ' first row and first column contain no intresting data
    ReDim data(1 To iRows - 1, 1 To iCols - 1)

   ' fill in data array
   For x = 1 To iRows - 1
    Set oRow = oTable.Rows(x)

    For y = 1 To iCols - 1
         If oRow.Cells(y).Children.Length > 0 Then
            data(x, y) = oRow.Cells(y).getelementsbytagname("a")(0).getattribute("href")

          '.Replace(data(x, y), "about:", "http://allscores.ru/soccer/")

        End If

       Next y
     Next x

     Set oRow = Nothing
     Set oTable = Nothing
     Set oDom = Nothing


    ' put data array on worksheet

     Set oRange = book1.ActiveSheet.Cells(34, iLoop * 25).Resize(iRows - 1, iCols - 1)
     oRange.NumberFormat = "@"
     oRange.Value = data

    oRange.Replace What:="about:", Replacement:="http://allscores.ru/soccer/"


     Set oRange = Nothing

     'Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:=",", LookAt:=xlPart, _
     SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
       ReplaceFormat:=False, MatchByte:=False


    '<DEBUG>
   '    For x = LBound(data) To UBound(data)
  '        Debug.Print x & ":[ ";
  '        For y = LBound(data, 2) To UBound(data, 2)
  '            Debug.Print y & ":[" & data(x, y) & "] ";
  '        Next y
  '        Debug.Print "]"
  '    Next x
   '</DEBUG>



   End Function
```

Comment: In the statement `Loop While Not r Is Nothing And r.Address <> firstAddress And iLoop < 19`, if `r` is `Nothing` the code will crash trying to obtain its `.Address` property.  (But luckily it should never be `Nothing` in that line.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @YowE3K, if `r is Nothing`, the VBA engine would continue evaluating the IF statement and would fail on `r.Address`.

Other languages behave differently, and would escape the check as soon as they find a false condition, but VBA does not do it this way - This is called *Short-circuit evaluation* - [Does the VBA "And" operator evaluate the second argument when the first is false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015471/does-the-vba-and-operator-evaluate-the-second-argument-when-the-first-is-false)

This is a way around:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim iloop           As Long
    Dim r               As Range
    Dim firstAddress    As String

    Do While True

        If r Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        If r.Address = firstAddress Then Exit Do
        If iloop < 10 Then Exit Do

        'Do the action

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I was thinking that `r` could never be `Nothing` at that point, because it can only enter the loop if the original `Find` found something, and therefore the `FindNext` would also find something (even if that was the original value).  But I guess if the cells being searched through contain formulas, and those formulas are being recalculated based on changes to the sheets, then it is possible that the `"1"` being searched for is no longer being calculated.  So that probably **is** the problem.

Comment: P.S.  I think you need to change the logic flow slightly so that it exits if `r.Address` **equals** `firstAddress` (i.e. if the `FindNext` returns to the original find).

Comment: @Vityata , I made changes in the code ,and the program does not do anything  , and why then before I inserted the line  (oRange.Replace What:="about:", Replacement:=http://allscores.ru/soccer/) everything worked ?