# Access VBA Check if all Checkboxes are FALSE

Tags: vba, checkbox, ms-access-2010

Good afternoon all

I have this piece of code to check if the checkboxes of my form are not checked, but each time I have this error message:
runtime error '438'

```
Private Sub Btn_Send_Click()
Dim ctl As Control
Dim iX As Integer

    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" And ctl.Value = False Then iX = iX + 1
    Next ctl

If iX = 0 Then MsgBox "No checkBox Selected", vbExclamation, "Title"

End Sub
```

Debbuging error :

```
If TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" And ctl.Value = False Then
```

> Run-Time Error #438: Object doesn't support this property or method

Thank you for your help

Comment: Either your message box is wrong or your logic is wrong. `iX` counts the number of checkboxes that are *not* checked. So when `iX = 0`, that means all checkboxes *are* checked and yet: `MsgBox "No checkbox Selected."`

Comment: @MoondogsMaDawg Bravooooooooo, I did not even notice this logic error. |  Big Up for you. | it solved the problem entirely !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do it like this:

```
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
        If ctl.Value = False Then
             iX = iX + 1
        End If
    End If
Next ctl
```

The reason is that VBA does not support **short-circuit evaluation** -
 [Does the VBA "And" operator evaluate the second argument when the first is false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015471/does-the-vba-and-operator-evaluate-the-second-argument-when-the-first-is-false)

Thus, even that your first condition is `False` it nicely goes and checks for your second condition. And if it is not a `CheckBox` control, then it throws an error, because it does not have a `.Value` property.

Comment: Well @Vityata, I tried your solution but I got this error message: #access reserved error 3201

Comment: @HoucineAdsens - where?

Comment: when I click on the button of my form to execute the code
#Reserved error (-3201) There is no message for this error
and that closes the form completely !!!!

Comment: @ Vityata: I think I'm going to rebuild my form.

Comment: @ Vityata:  Thank you very Much