# Application.Index and Application.Match with multi-criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I want to lookup the value from a SourceSheet based on two criteria, and return the value in column 7 to the TargetSheet. This is to pull financial data like the overall margin % for a jobs subtype.

Not all the TargetSheets rows (Criteria1 & Criteria3) will be found in the SourceSheet, and some will be found but the value will be blank.
This results in the code throwing a type mismatch error during the below portion:

```
If IsError(Application.Index(SourceRange, Application.Match(Criteria1 & Criteria2, SourceRange.Columns(4) & SourceRange.Columns(5), 0), 6)) Then
```

I tried different ways, but all result in the type mismatch.

```vb
Sub Margin_Trade_Update()

Dim SourceWB As Workbook, TargetWB As Workbook
Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet, TargetSheet As Worksheet
Dim Criteria1 As String, Criteria2 As String
Dim SourceRange As Range, TargetRange As Range
Dim MatchLC As Long, MatchTrade As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ResultCol As Long

'Set the source and target workbooks
Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open("Path and Source workbook name")
Set TargetWB = ThisWorkbook

'Set the source and target worksheets
Set SourceSheet = SourceWB.Sheets("Margin - Trade")
Set TargetSheet = TargetWB.Sheets("01-25")

'Delete the first two rows of margin trade sheet
SourceSheet.Range("A1:A2").EntireRow.Delete

'Determine the last row in the target sheet
LastRow = TargetSheet.Cells(TargetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Iterate through the rows in the target sheet for MTD Trade Margin

For i = 2 To LastRow
    
    'Set the criteria and target range
    Criteria1 = TargetSheet.Cells(i, "H").Value
    Criteria2 = TargetSheet.Cells(i, "M").Value
    Set TargetRange = TargetSheet.Cells(i, "AB")
    
    'Find the match row and column in the source range
    With SourceSheet
        Set SourceRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count))
        MatchLC = IIf(IsError(Application.Match(Criteria1, .Columns(4), 0)), 0, Application.Match(Criteria1, .Columns(4), 0))
        MatchTrade = IIf(IsError(Application.Match(Criteria2, .Columns(5), 0)), 0, Application.Match(Criteria2, .Columns(5), 0))
    End With

    'Use INDEX and MATCH to retrieve the value from the source range
    If IsError(Application.Index(SourceRange, Application.Match(Criteria1 & Criteria2, SourceRange.Columns(4) & SourceRange.Columns(5), 0), 6)) Then
        TargetRange.Value = ""
    Else
        TargetRange.Value = Application.Index(SourceRange, Application.Match(Criteria1 & Criteria2, SourceRange.Columns(4) & SourceRange.Columns(5), 0), 6)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

Next i

'Close the source workbook
SourceWB.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

The final code and some comments for changes I made:

```vb
'Needed to define the function so instead of figuring out how to nest it i just went the 'ol fashioned way

Function MatchOrZero(ByVal LookupVal As Variant, ByVal LookupRange As Range, Optional ByVal ReturnType As Long = 1) As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    MatchOrZero = Application.Match(LookupVal, LookupRange, ReturnType)
    If IsError(MatchOrZero) Then
        MatchOrZero = 0
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function


Sub Margin_Trade_Update_V3()

' Update JCA tab with MTD Trade Margin

Dim SourceWB As Workbook, TargetWB As Workbook
Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet, TargetSheet As Worksheet
Dim SourceRange As Range, TargetRangeMTD As Range, TargetRangeLTD As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ResultCol As Long

'Set the source and target workbooks
Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open("Path & File Here")
Set TargetWB = ThisWorkbook

'Set the source and target worksheets
Set SourceSheet = SourceWB.Sheets("Margin - Trade")
Set TargetSheet = TargetWB.Sheets("01-25")

'Delete the first two rows of margin trade sheet
SourceSheet.Range("A1:A2").EntireRow.Delete

'Determine the last row in the target sheet
LastRow = TargetSheet.Cells(TargetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Iterate through the rows in the target sheet for MTD Trade Margin
Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To LastRow
    
    'Set the criteria and target range
    Dim Criteria1 As String, Criteria2 As String
    Criteria1 = TargetSheet.Cells(i, "H").Value
    Criteria2 = TargetSheet.Cells(i, "M").Value
    Set TargetRangeMTD = TargetSheet.Cells(i, "AB")
    Set TargetRangeLTD = TargetSheet.Cells(i, "AC")
    
    'Find the match row and column in the source range
    With SourceSheet
        Set SourceRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count))
        Dim MatchLC As Long
        MatchLC = MatchOrZero(Criteria1, .Columns(4), 0)
        Dim MatchTrade As Long
        MatchTrade = MatchOrZero(Criteria2, .Columns(5), 0)
    End With

    'Use INDEX and MATCH to retrieve the value from the source range
    Dim MyMatch As Variant
    'N/A by default
    MyMatch = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        
    Dim LookUpRange1 As Range
    Dim LookUpRange2 As Range
'needed to define SourceSheetLastRow
    Dim SourceSheetLastRow As Long
    SourceSheetLastRow = SourceSheet.Cells(SourceSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    If LookUpRange1 Is Nothing Then
        Set LookUpRange1 = SourceSheet.Range(SourceSheet.Cells(1, 4), SourceSheet.Cells(SourceSheetLastRow, 4))
        Set LookUpRange2 = SourceSheet.Range(SourceSheet.Cells(1, 5), SourceSheet.Cells(SourceSheetLastRow, 5))
                
        'Here we are storing the values from the ranges inside arrays. This is mainly to improve performance as VBA doesn't have to access the worksheet data constantly.
        Dim arr1() As Variant
        'Note here that you don't need to specify Columns(1) if LookUpRange is always a single-column range.
        arr1 = LookUpRange1.Columns(1).Value2
        Dim arr2() As Variant
    arr2 = LookUpRange2.Columns(1).Value2
    End If
        
    Dim j As Long
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr1)
        If arr1(j, 1) = Criteria1 Then
            If arr2(j, 1) = Criteria2 Then
                'MyMatch = i - Needed to be j in this loop
                MyMatch = j
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next j
         
    If IsError(MyMatch) Then
        TargetRangeMTD.Value = ""
        TargetRangeLTD.Value = ""
    Else
        TargetRangeMTD.Value2 = Application.Index(SourceRange, MyMatch, 6)
        TargetRangeLTD.Value2 = Application.Index(SourceRange, MyMatch, 7)
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem comes from the fact that you are trying to combine two ranges with the "&" operator when you do `SourceRange.Columns(4) & SourceRange.Columns(5)`. You are trying to concatenate two ranges, but VBA only knows how to concatenate strings or types that can be converted to string directly, so this explains the type error.

In this case, since you are trying to do a multi-criteria match in VBA, you can't exactly use the syntax that you would normally use in Excel when you use dynamic array formulas.

If you want to use that syntax you would have to create your own helper column with the data from column 3 and 4 concatenated.

Or you could also use a custom VBA function like this :

```vb
Function MatchWith2Criteria(LookUpRange1 As Range, Criteria1 As Variant, LookUpRange2 As Range, Criteria2 As Variant) As Variant

    'N/A by default
    MatchWith2Criteria = CVErr(xlErrNA)

    'We need the two ranges to have the same height or we won't be able to align them
    If (LookUpRange1.Rows.Count <> LookUpRange2.Rows.Count) Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    'Here we are storing the values from the ranges inside arrays. This is mainly to improve performance as VBA doesn't have to access the worksheet data constantly.
    Dim arr1() As Variant
    arr1 = LookUpRange1.Columns(1).Value2
    Dim arr2() As Variant
    arr2 = LookUpRange2.Columns(1).Value2
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr1)
        If arr1(i, 1) = Criteria1 And arr2(i, 1) = Criteria2 Then
            MatchWith2Criteria = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Then, you could do something like this in your code:

```vb
        Dim MyMatch As Variant
        MyMatch = MatchWith2Criteria(SourceSheet.Columns(3), Criteria1, SourceSheet.Columns(4), Criteria2)
        If IsError(MyMatch) Then
            TargetRange.Value2 = ""
        Else
            TargetRange.Value2 = Application.Index(SourceRange,MyMatch,6)
        End If
```

**About performance (update)**

As you mentioned in the comments, this approach can be slow when you have a lot of data, so one solution is to reduce the amount of data involved.

To reduce the amount of data involved, you could pass a range with limited size instead of passing the whole column. Then `SourceSheet.Columns(3)` would then become something like this:

```vb
SourceSheet.Range(SourceSheet.Cells(1,3),SourceSheet.Cells(SourceSheetLastRow,3))
```

Where you can calculate `SourceSheetLastRow` the same way you did for `LastRow`, ie:

```vb
'Determine the last row in the source sheet (based on column A)
SourceSheetLastRow = SourceSheet.Cells(SourceSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

This will likely help with the performance, but you could also go further to improve performance by reducing the number of access to the spreadsheet by incorporating the code of the function inside your procedure like this:

```vb
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To LastRow
    
        'Set the criteria and target range
        Dim Criteria1 As String, Criteria2 As String
        Criteria1 = TargetSheet.Cells(i, "C").Value
        Criteria2 = TargetSheet.Cells(i, "D").Value
        Set TargetRange = TargetSheet.Cells(i, "B")
    
        'Find the match row and column in the source range
        With SourceSheet
            Set SourceRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count))
            Dim MatchLC As Long
            MatchLC = MatchOrZero(Criteria1, .Columns(3), 0)
            Dim MatchTrade As Long
            MatchTrade = MatchOrZero(Criteria2, .Columns(4), 0)
        End With

        'Use INDEX and MATCH to retrieve the value from the source range
        Dim MyMatch As Variant
        'N/A by default
        MyMatch = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        
        Dim LookUpRange1 As Range
        Dim LookUpRange2 As Range
        
        If LookUpRange1 Is Nothing Then
            Set LookUpRange1 = SourceSheet.Range(SourceSheet.Cells(1, 3), SourceSheet.Cells(SourceSheetLastRow, 3))
            Set LookUpRange2 = SourceSheet.Range(SourceSheet.Cells(1, 4), SourceSheet.Cells(SourceSheetLastRow, 4))
                
            'Here we are storing the values from the ranges inside arrays. This is mainly to improve performance as VBA doesn't have to access the worksheet data constantly.
            Dim arr1() As Variant
            'Note here that you don't need to specify Columns(1) if LookUpRange is always a single-column range.
            arr1 = LookUpRange1.Columns(1).Value2
            Dim arr2() As Variant
            arr2 = LookUpRange2.Columns(1).Value2
        End If
        
        Dim j As Long
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr1)
            If arr1(j, 1) = Criteria1 Then
                If arr2(j, 1) = Criteria2 Then
                    MyMatch = i
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next j
         
        If IsError(MyMatch) Then
            TargetRange.Value = ""
        Else
            TargetRange.Value2 = Application.Index(SourceRange, MyMatch, 6)
        End If

    Next i
```

The trick here is that `LookUpRange1 Is Nothing` will be true only on the first iteration of the for-loop, so it allows us to read from the sheet data only once.

Note that we're also using a nested if-statements for the criterions, so we don't eveluate the second criterion if the first is false (more on why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7020502/5958842)).

There's probably more tricks you could use such as the ones discussed in [this article](https://analystcave.com/excel-improve-vba-performance/). The ones that would help the most here are probably the first two. Here's how I usually use them:

```vb
    Dim InitialCalculationMode As Variant: InitialCalculationMode = Application.Calculation

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    
    On Error GoTo RestoreAppConfig
    
    'Your code that takes a while to run
    
RestoreAppConfig:

    With Application
        .Calculation = InitialCalculationMode
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
```

---

Alternatively, you could also pass an array to the Match function with the two columns already concatenated elementwise. You could perform the concatenation with a function like this :

```vb
Function ConcatenateElementWise(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range) As Variant()

    'Convert to array
    Dim arr1() as Variant
    arr1 = rng1.Value2
    Dim arr2() as Variant
    arr2 = rng2.Value2
          
    Dim result() As Variant
    ReDim result(LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1))
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
        result(i) = arr1(i, 1) & arr2(i, 1)
    Next i

    ConcatenateElementWise = result
    
End Function
```

And then replace `SourceRange.Columns(4) & SourceRange.Columns(5)` with `ConcatenateElementWise(SourceRange.Columns(4), SourceRange.Columns(5))`

Comment: Thank you! This is great! I am still pretty new to VBA and I havent done Functions yet. 

Do I need to set the range for rng1 and rng2? When I enter this code to the below updated code, it seems to be calculating but I havent let it go for more than 10 minutes, so I assume something isnt quite right...

Comment: @Nodnarb, it shouldn't take that long. What have you done exactly?

Comment: I actually went back and used your custom function, just copy paste before the Sub(), then changed the old If Else End-If to the Dim MyMatch section. I put the Dim MyMatch inside the For i=2 portion jsut before the Next i. The one caveat I think may be an issue is that the TargetRange is ~10,000 rows and the SourceRange is ~1,500 rows long.

I have updated the original post with the code as it is now

Comment: @Nodnarb, I've updated my answer to give some suggestions regarding optimization

Comment: Thank you very much, @DecimalTurn! This is resolved! Very good information and you have been absolutely wonderful! I am going to mark this as solved!