# How is an Or statement evaluated in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am just wondering how does an `Or` conditional statement work in VBA/VB6. Basically, if we have `If A Or B Then`, in what order are the Boolean expressions evaluated? If A is true, is B also evaluated?

Comment: both will be evaluated regardless.  In VBA I believe the only way around is to split them both into separated nested if statements.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264205.aspx

Comment: Previously: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641923/vba-short-circuit-and-alternatives , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242560/andalso-orelse-in-vba/3245183#3245183

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some test results for you:

```
Public Sub DoTesting()

    ' Displays "Test1" followed by "Test2", so they're evaluated in order.
    ' Also, both expressions are evaluated even though Test1() is False.
    If Test1() And Test2() Then
    End If

    ' Displays "Test2" followed by "Test1", so they're evaluated in order.
    ' Also, both expressions are evaluated even though Test2() is True.
    If Test2() Or Test1() Then
    End If

    ' Displays "Test1" only. Test2() is not evaluated.
    If Test1() Then If Test2() Then Debug.Print ""

End Sub

Public Function Test1() As Boolean
    MsgBox "Test1"
    Test1 = False
End Function

Public Function Test2() As Boolean
    MsgBox "Test2"
    Test2 = True
End Function
```

So, both expressions in an `Or` or an `And` are always evaluated, in order, regardless of outcome. You can use `If ... Then If ... Then` to achieve simple inline short-circuiting.