# Opposite of LIKE statement

Tags: vba, excel

I am having some issues getting a `If NOT Like` code to work.

Below is the part of the coding that has it. It seems like the coding is bringing over the second record that has *Rail* in the field being looked at, but none of the records with rail before that one or after that one.

In reality, it should be bringing over records that don't contain rail anywhere in that field but it doesn't do that either. Any feedback is appreciated.

```
Set rngData = Intersect(wsData.UsedRange, wsData.Range("A:K"))

    j = 1
    rngData.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=wsGalreq.Cells(j, 1)

    For i = 2 To rngData.Rows.Count
        If Not rngData.Cells(i, 11).Value = "SUPPLIER A" And rngData.Cells(i, 6).Value Like "*RAIL*" Then
            j = j + 1
            rngData.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=wsGalreq.Cells(j, 1)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Here's the [Operator Precedence table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278455.aspx) in VBA for future reference

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use brackets or logic to explicitly state what you are after.

```
If Not rngData.Cells(i, 11).Value = "SUPPLIER A" And rngData.Cells(i, 6).Value Like "*RAIL*" Then
```

is the same as

```
If Not A And B
```

when it appears you want

```
If Not A And Not B
```

Comment: or it could be `IF Not (A And B)`

Comment: Perfect @Alex McMillan, I was able to use:
    IF A And Not B as I actually wanted it to select Supplier A records but not ones that included "Rail" in the description. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As VBA [doesn't short circuit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641923/vba-short-circuit-and-alternatives) it is better to write logic as below with the more likely *False* condition first (so the redundant second test isn't run).

So

`If Not A Then
  If Not B`

Or in your case;

```
If Not rngData.Cells(i, 11).Value = "SUPPLIER A" Then
    If Not rngData.Cells(i, 6).Value Like "*RAIL*" Then
            j = j + 1
            rngData.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=wsGalreq.Cells(j, 1)
    End If
 End If
```