# VBA - IF evaluation

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, evaluation

I am pretty sure that in most languages you can secure the evaluation of a condition by doing one of the following:

```
if FALSE and (1/0 = 0) {...}
```

or

```
if TRUE or (1/0 = 0) {...}
```

Those examples should not throw exeptions (maybe the second one depending on internal implementation of the evaluation) as the whole if-condition is met even without checking the second condition.

In VBA however both these protections wont work:

```
If False and t() Then ...
If True or t() Then ...

Function t() As Boolean
MsgBox "This is displayed both times"
End Function
```

Why does VBA behave this way and what is the best (+shortest) way to do these kind of protections instead?

Example: `If s = "" or thisFunctionCantTakeEmptyStrings(s) Then ...`

Comment: This already has been asked, it's called short-circuit. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641923/vba-short-circuit-and-alternatives

Comment: Ah ok I did not know the name of this, and therefore did not find much on this. Thank your for the reference