# Expediting VBA Code for comparing two sheets and deleting rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code completed and basically all it does is compare between two different sheets in excel.  It looks at certain columns and if they match it goes to the next step etc.  as of right now the code takes about a minute to complete and that is if Excel doesnt crash after it does complete.  So I was wondering if there was a better way to compare these two sheets instead of having the Activate command that i use in order to switch back and forth.  There are 2200 rows so it is a lot of data.  See below and let me know if there was a better way to do this.  Thanks!

```
For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    cell1 = Cells(i, 2)
    Worksheets("Validations").Activate
For j = Blastrow To 2 Step -1
    cell2 = Cells(j, 2)
    If cell1 = cell2 Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
        cell1 = Cells(i, "BY")
        Worksheets("Validations").Activate
        cell2 = Cells(j, "BY")
        
        
        If cell1 = cell2 Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
            cell1 = Cells(i, "CD")
            Worksheets("Validations").Activate
            cell2 = Cells(j, "CD")
            
            
            If cell1 = cell2 Then
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
                cell1 = Cells(i, "O")
                If IsEmpty(cell1) Then
                cell1 = Cells(i, "S")
                    If IsEmpty(cell1) Then
                        cell1 = Cells(i, "W")
                    End If
                End If
                Worksheets("Validations").Activate
                cell2 = Cells(j, "O")
                If IsEmpty(cell2) Then
                    cell2 = Cells(j, "S")
                    If IsEmpty(cell2) Then
                        cell1 = Cells(j, "W")
                    End If
                End If
                
                
                If cell1 = cell2 Then
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
                    cell1 = Cells(i, "Q")
                    If IsEmpty(cell1) Then
                        cell1 = Cells(i, "U")
                        If IsEmpty(cell1) Then
                            cell1 = Cells(i, "Y")
                        End If
                    End If
                    Worksheets("Validations").Activate
                    cell2 = Cells(j, "Q")
                    If IsEmpty(cell2) Then
                        cell2 = Cells(j, "U")
                        If IsEmpty(cell2) Then
                            cell1 = Cells(j, "Y")
                        End If
                    End If

                    If cell1 = cell2 Then
                        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
                        Cells(i, "CL") = "Approve"
                        Exit For
                    Else
                        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
                        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Else
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
                    Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
                    Exit For
                End If
            Else
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
                Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
                Exit For
            End If
        Else
            'delete row from sheet1
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
        Exit For
    End If
    If j = 2 Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        Exit For
    End If
Next j
Next i
Worksheets("Validations").Delete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Activate` is not essential and, in fact, should be avoided.

Please refer to

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10717999#10717999)

Your code can be optimized for efficiency as shown below. Please apply the same improvements to the remaining portions.

```
    Dim Sht1 As Worksheet, ShtV As Workbook
    Set Sht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ShtV = Worksheets("Validations")
    For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
        cell1 = Sht1.Cells(i, 2)
        For j = Blastrow To 2 Step -1
            cell2 = ShtV.Cells(j, 2)
            If cell1 = cell2 Then
                cell1 = Sht1.Cells(i, "BY")
                cell2 = ShtV.Cells(j, "BY")
                If cell1 = cell2 Then
                    cell1 = Sht1.Cells(i, "CD")
                    cell2 = ShtV.Cells(j, "CD")
                    If cell1 = cell2 Then
```

---

The nested `If` could be simplified as below.

Note: The suggested code changes do not constitute efficiency improvements, as pointed out in `chris neilsen`'s comment.

```
Dim Sht1 As Worksheet, ShtV As Workbook
Set Sht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ShtV = Worksheets("Validations")
For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
    For j = Blastrow To 2 Step -1
        If Sht1.Cells(i, 2)=ShtV.Cells(j, 2) And _
            Sht1.Cells(i, "BY")=ShtV.Cells(j, "BY") And _
            Sht1.Cells(i, "CD")=ShtV.Cells(j, "CD") Then 
            ' Your code
        Else
            ' Your code
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: fyi changing to OPs nested If's to a sinlge If with And's is less efficient, due to [VBA not supporting Short-Circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24641923)

Comment: Agree. Avoiding the use of Activate is done for the sake of efficiency, the other is not. I have updated the reply. Thx