# Declaring more than one Condition in IF statement for same result

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a scenario where I need two conditions in an IF statement to show the same result.

i.e:

```
 IF Condition 1 = something AND Condition 2 = Anything           
   txtMessage = "Hello world."

 Else
   txtMessage = "Goodbye world.
```

Condition 1 being the 'Tag' option for controls in Access, and Condition 2 being the text in the control such as "N/A".

I know in Java you can use && to declare this, but how can I do this in VBA? I've checked out similar questions in the forums and Google but couldn't find an answer for this. Other people suggest using elseif statements, but there should be a way to declare two conditions which result in the same thing in one line, no? Am I over-looking something simple here, or is this the wrong way to look at it?

*EDIT*

Here is a snippet of the code I am using

```
If ctrl.Tag = "BlkChk" Then
    If IsNull(ctrl) Then
       strMsg = strMsg & "- " & ctrl.Name & vbCrLf
    End If
End If
```

Basically, I would like this code to check if the control is either blank, or contains the text "N/A" If so, print the text " Hello World." If not, print the text "Goodbye world."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to achieve the same as && in Java, that is called a short-circuit.  The way it works is that only if the first condition evaluates as true is the second condition evaluated.  A short-circuit is not available in VBA, but you can achieve something similar with a Switch statement.

See: 
[AndAlso/OrElse in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242560/andalso-orelse-in-vba)

Comment: I figured it was something as simple as this. Thanks Will H!

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying you want `txtMessage` to equal "Hello world." if either of the conditions are true or if both conditions are true?

If the former, use the keyword `Or`. If the latter, use the keyword `And`.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz3k228a.aspx

Comment: I'll edit this question to show the syntax. I forgot to initially add it.