# What means If * Then * And condition

Tags: vba, excel

i have maybe a simple question, but its blowing my mind. I have some code to refactor it a bit, but cant figure out what author thinks by this statement

```
If (j > 0) Then greatThanPrec = greatThanPrec And (signalAmplArray(i) > signalAmplArray(j))
```

I think i know how basic `If Then else` works, but cant realize why is something like `A = A` after then, and then is `AND` maybe some short condition like in C/C++?

Comment: no, it's a **logical** (bitwise) AND. Then it means that "if the condition is met, change the value of A to `A And B`".

Comment: `And`, `Or` are Boolean (True/False) operators. The `greatThanPrec` is a Boolean type here.

Comment: @PatricK In VBA, `And` and `Or` are bitwise. They work just as fine in logical contexts, but they are inherently bitwise (as opposed to `AndAlso` and `OrElse` in VB.NET).

Comment: @GSerg Thanks, didn't notice it before. I can confirm in immediate window with `?1 Or 2` (=3) and `?2 And 3` (=2). This opens up some tweaks for some calculations for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That particular `And` has nothing to do with `If Then`.

The code after `Then` simply updates `greatThanPrec` depending on whether `signalAmplArray(i) > signalAmplArray(j)` or not. `greatThanPrec` will stay `True` if both `greatThanPrec` and `signalAmplArray(i) > signalAmplArray(j)` are `True`, otherwise it will become `False`.

To better see it, replace `signalAmplArray(i) > signalAmplArray(j)` with its possible values. You will get two options:

```
greatThanPrec = greatThanPrec And True  'greatThanPrec does not change its value
```

```
greatThanPrec = greatThanPrec And False 'greatThanPrec becomes false
```

If you want to refactor it, that would be

```
If (j > 0) Then
  If Not (signalAmplArray(i) > signalAmplArray(j)) Then
    greatThanPrec = False
  End If
End If
```

Comment: Is the AND here a logical Connector or does it just Connet two Lines after the Then?

Comment: `And` never connects two lines. You use `:` in VBA to put multiple statements on one line. That is, you can write code where you have boolean functions that have side effects, and you can call them on one line like `= CauseEffects() And CauseMoreEffects()`, but that is both not what is happening here and is bad code, especially for people who don't realize VBA [does not have short circuit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3242560/11683).

Comment: @Moosli the And here is a Logical conjunction yes.

Comment: @Gserg: Thanks for the explanation and the Link. I learned something new

Comment: @GSerg thanks for great answer ;) didnt thought its so simple