# Incorrect use of DLookup in if statement VBA MSAccess

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to use an if statement to determine if a text field contains a value from a database. Except I get an error when nothing is entered.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub btnLogEntry_Click()


If Me.txtMemberID.Value <> "" And DLookup("MemberID", "Member", "MemberID = " & Me.txtMemberID.Value & "") > 0 Then
MsgBox "Entry Successful", vbInformation, "Alert"
MsgBox "Welcome", vbInformation, "Alert"
TempVars!activtyMemberID = Me.txtMemberID.Value
TempVars!activityTime = Me.txtTime.Value
TempVars!activityAccessType = Me.txtAccessType.Value
TempVars!activityFranchiseID = DLookup("[FranchiseID]", "Member", "MemberID = " & Me.txtMemberID.Value)
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO GymActivity VALUES (Tempvars!activtyMemberID, 
Tempvars!activityTime, Tempvars!activityAccessType, 
Tempvars!activityFranchiseID)"

DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMainPage"
Else
MsgBox "Please re-enter your Member ID"

End If
End Sub
```

Here is the error I receive:
https://imagebin.ca/v/3ZBvRiXlZM2t

Comment: Spelling error on `activtyMemberID` ! You really sould use `option explicit` at top of your module and declare your variables to avoid that kind of errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your edge case. I.e. when the `txtMemberID.Text == ""`.

Do note that VBA have a very limited support of lazy evaluation - i.e. evaluation of nested conditions, only if the evaluated ones have passed the check so far - and the `And` operator does not fall in this support, meaning all the conditions, concatenated with the `And` statement are evaluated in order of appearance, even if the first (leftmost) ones in the line result into `False`.

So when there is no text in the `txtMemberID` textbox, the `DCount(...` function is still evaluated and ... bang you'll end up with malformed expression for criteria; just as shown in the error message.

Two options are available to overcome this situation. The lazy evaluation is supported only [within the `Select Case` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242560/andalso-orelse-in-vba).

The other option is to nest your `If` statements, like so:

```
Private Sub btnLogEntry_Click()

If Me.txtMemberID.Value <> "" Then
    If DLookup("MemberID", "Member", "MemberID = " & Me.txtMemberID.Value & "") > 0
        MsgBox "Entry Successful", vbInformation, "Alert"
        MsgBox "Welcome", vbInformation, "Alert"
        TempVars!activtyMemberID = Me.txtMemberID.Value
        TempVars!activityTime = Me.txtTime.Value
        TempVars!activityAccessType = Me.txtAccessType.Value
        TempVars!activityFranchiseID = DLookup("[FranchiseID]", "Member", "MemberID = " & Me.txtMemberID.Value)
        DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO GymActivity VALUES (Tempvars!activtyMemberID, 
        Tempvars!activityTime, Tempvars!activityAccessType, 
        Tempvars!activityFranchiseID)"

        DoCmd.Close
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMainPage"
    Else
        MsgBox "The specified MemberID not found."
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "Please re-enter your Member ID"    
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take advantage of the fact, that DLookup returns *Null* for "not found" and look up FranchiseID in one go:

```
Private Sub btnLogEntry_Click()

    Dim FranchiseID As Variant

    If Not IsNumeric(Me.txtMemberID.Value) Then
        ' None or invalid user input. Exit.
        MsgBox "A member ID is required."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    FranchiseID = DLookup("[FranchiseID]", "Member", "MemberID = " & Me.txtMemberID.Value & "")

    If Not IsNull(FranchiseID) Then
        MsgBox "Entry Successful", vbInformation, "Alert"
        MsgBox "Welcome", vbInformation, "Alert"

        TempVars!activtyMemberID = Me.txtMemberID.Value
        TempVars!activityTime = Me.txtTime.Value
        TempVars!activityAccessType = Me.txtAccessType.Value
        TempVars!activityFranchiseID = FranchiseID

        DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO GymActivity VALUES (Tempvars!activtyMemberID, Tempvars!activityTime, Tempvars!activityAccessType, Tempvars!activityFranchiseID)"

        DoCmd.Close
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMainPage"
    Else
        MsgBox "Please re-enter your Member ID"            
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That will still fail if txtMemberID is equal to a zero-length string, since it will produce an invalid `WHERE` statement in the `DLookUp` (`WHERE MemberID = `, since MemberID is a number, it won't have any delimiters thus is invalid). The approach by @Bozhidar-Stoinev avoids this error.

Comment: An unbound textbox will not hold an empty string. But what's missing is a way to escape. That has been added.

Comment: Ah, yes, my wording is incorrect, but the point isn't. Because if `Me.txtMemberID.Value` is `Null`, the result will be the same (concatenating a string with `Null` yields the same result as concatenating a string with a zero-length string). I see you've corrected the error, though.